# apply - test multiple conditions before moving rows

Tags: r, loops, apply

I want to use apply to iterate over a matrix comparing open and high prices to a limit.

I originally used a while loop but it was slow so moved to apply.

I have tried to +1 to the StartingRow as below.

```
Summary <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=1)
Overall <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=2)
Open <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=1, ncol=1)

MSingle <- function(x, StartingRow=1, Limit=0.01, StopLoss=0.01){
  Open = x[1]
  High = x[2]
  Low = x[3]
  #If the difference between High and Open exceeds Limit the function ends.
  if (!is.na(High-Open[StartingRow]) > Limit){
    Summary <<- 1
    Open <<- Open
    Row <<- cbind(Summary, Open)
    Overall <<- rbind(Overall, Row)
  }
  #If the difference between Open and Low exceeds the Stoploss the function ends.
  else if (!is.na(Open[StartingRow]-Low) > StopLoss){
    Summary <<- 0
    Open <<- Open
    Row <<- cbind(Summary, Open)
    Overall <<- rbind(Overall, Row)
  }
  #If neither of these are met then I want to compare the original Open price at time t...
  #...with the high and low prices at time t+1, t+2, and so on, until either of the first two...
  #...conditions is met.
  else{
    StartingRow = StartingRow + 1
  }
}

apply(EUR_USD2, 1, MSingle)
```

CORRECTION: This was initially lapply but it was an error on my part when copying code over, the result described is from apply.

Example of Matrix EUR_USD2

```
       Open    High     Low   Close
[1,] 1.20037 1.20100 1.20037 1.20100
[2,] 1.20083 1.20095 1.20017 1.20030
[3,] 1.20035 1.20043 1.20035 1.20043
[4,] 1.20041 1.20050 1.20031 1.20046
[5,] 1.20049 1.20049 1.20046 1.20048`
[6,] 1.20050 1.20050 1.20048 1.20048
[7,] 1.20050 1.20069 1.20032 1.20048
[8,] 1.20048 1.20054 1.20027 1.20050
[9,] 1.20051 1.20087 1.20047 1.20087
[10,] 1.20082 1.20097 1.20076 1.20094
```

Intended results:

```
High[1] = 1.20100
Open[1] = 1.20037
Difference is 0.00063 (which is < Limit)
```

Therefore I want to retain the same Open[1] but move to High[2].

```
High[2] = 1.20095
Open[1] = 1.20037
```

Difference is 0.00058 (which is < Limit) and so on, until the difference is greater than Limit (or less than stoploss) at which point the function starts again but with Open[2].

Result of apply:

```
     Summary    Open
          NA      NA
Open       1 1.20037
Open       1 1.20083
Open       1 1.20035
Open       1 1.20041
Open       1 1.20049
Open       1 1.20050
Open       1 1.20050
Open       1 1.20048
Open       1 1.20051
```

This result however is only comparing the (High-Open) to Limit for the same period.

I want to compare High-Open (the difference) to the Limit. If this exceeds the limit then the first condition is met. If the condition is not met then I want to retain the same Open price but compare that to the High of the next period and test again against the Limit.

Only then do I want apply to move onto comparing the Open and High from period 2 to Limit.

The Open price must remain the same until the condition is met. Currently apply is comparing High(t=1)-Open(t=1) to Limit but does not compare the Open to any future periods High Values.

Comment: I have tried lapply, sapply and apply.

Correction: the result I am getting is from straight apply. I will change the original code.

I will also look into <<- thanks for the advice.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I've tried that many variations I don't know if I'm coming or going.

Comment: The results will be similar to the results above, in that 1 means the Limit was hit first, 0 if the Stoploss was hit first.

The results above however only consider that particular row as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understood the output you are expecting (you could add to your post and example of the exact result you expect), but something similar to what I propose might work:

```
s <- "Open High Low Close
1.20037 1.20100 1.20037 1.20100
1.20083 1.20095 1.20017 1.20030
1.20035 1.20043 1.20035 1.20043
1.20041 1.20050 1.20031 1.20046
1.20049 1.20049 1.20046 1.20048
1.20050 1.20050 1.20048 1.20048
1.20050 1.20069 1.20032 1.20048
1.20048 1.20054 1.20027 1.20050
1.20051 1.20087 1.20047 1.20087
1.20082 1.20097 1.20076 1.20094"

EUR_USD2 <- read.delim(textConnection(s), sep = " ")

myfun <- function(x, df, Limit, StopLoss) {

  highComp <- which(df$High - df$Open[x] > Limit)
  highCompMin <- if(length(highComp) == 0) 0 else min(highComp)
  lowComp <- which(df$Open[x] - df$Low > StopLoss)
  lowCompMin <- if(length(lowComp) == 0) 0 else min(lowComp)

  if(highCompMin == 0 & lowCompMin == 0) {
    result <- c(Summary = NA, Open = df$Open[x])
  } else if (highCompMin >= lowCompMin) {
    result <- c(Summary = 1, Open = df$Open[x])
  } else if (lowCompMin > highCompMin) {
    result <- c(Summary = 0, Open = df$Open[x])
  } else {
    result <- c(Summary = NA, Open = df$Open[x])
  }

  return(result)

}

t(sapply(1:nrow(EUR_USD2), function(x) myfun(x, df = EUR_USD2,
                                             Limit = 0.00062, StopLoss = 0.0005)))

### OUTPUT:
#      Summary    Open
# [1,]       1 1.20037
# [2,]       0 1.20083
# [3,]       1 1.20035
# [4,]      NA 1.20041
# [5,]      NA 1.20049
# [6,]      NA 1.20050
# [7,]      NA 1.20050
# [8,]      NA 1.20048
# [9,]      NA 1.20051
# [10,]      0 1.20082
```

For each row `i` compares `EUR_USD2$Open[i]` with the whole `High` and `Low` columns to find the minimum index that fulfills the comparisons and then sets `Summary` according to the result. The value is set to `NA` in case no value fulfills the comparisons.

Comment: To me the explanation of desired results makes sense but it always seems that way. Is there anything in particular that is ambiguous?

Comment: I tried your code but it's not the desired result. If we set the limit on your code to 0.00062 then the difference between 1.20037 and 1.20100 exceeds the limit and the output should be 1 (whereas when I run it I get 0)

If we consider row 3 above with Open = 1.20035 and High= 1.20043 we get a difference of 0.00008. If the Limit is set to greater than this, say 0.0001 then I want it to compare the difference between the original Open (1.20035) with the High of period 4 (1.20050). At this point the difference 0.00015 exceeds the Limit and the output should be 1.

Comment: Doing `t(sapply(1:nrow(EUR_USD2), function(x) myfun(x, Limit = 0.00062, StopLoss = 0.01)))` I got Summary 1 for Open 1.20037 and 1.20035 and NA for the rest of values for Open

Comment: How strange. I'm getting Summary 0 for all values of Open.

      Summary    Open
 [1,]       0 1.20037
 [2,]       0 1.20083
 [3,]       0 1.20035
 [4,]       0 1.20041
 [5,]       0 1.20049
 [6,]       0 1.20050
 [7,]       0 1.20050
 [8,]       0 1.20048
 [9,]       0 1.20051
[10,]       0 1.20082

Comment: I edited the main answer with a code that can be directly reproduced and I show the output there. If we would still have different results, I would be really curious to figure out why.

Comment: The edited code worked. I started it in a new project with the df reference as before and it worked.

Thanks for your help.