# parSapply error. Function works without Parallel

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, parallel-processing

I have a working function but when running on AWS EC2 it only uses a single core and I want to convert to parallel

Original problem solved (without Parallel) at: [apply - test multiple conditions before moving rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838974/apply-test-multiple-conditions-before-moving-rows/56851189?noredirect=1#comment100280089_56851189)

I have installed the Intel MKL on the AWS EC2 server and that still runs using only a single core. I have tried to edit the code as below.

```
PipSize <- 0.00886

myfun <- function(x, df = EURUSD, Limit = PipSize, StopLoss = PipSize) {

  highComp <- which(df$High - df$Open[x] > Limit)
  highCompMin <- if(length(highComp) == 0) 0 else min(highComp)
  lowComp <- which(df$Open[x] - df$Low > StopLoss)
  lowCompMin <- if(length(lowComp) == 0) 0 else min(lowComp)

  if(highCompMin == 0 & lowCompMin == 0) {
    result <<- c(Limit = NA, Open = df$Open[x])
  } else if (highCompMin <= lowCompMin) {
    result <<- c(Limit = 1, Open = df$Open[x])
  } else {
    result <<- c(Limit= 0, Open = df$Open[x])
  }

  return(result)

}

t(sapply(1:10, function(x) myfun(x, df = EURUSD, Limit = PipSize, StopLoss = PipSize)))
```

Additional Parallel code that returns error

```
library("parallel")
library("doParallel")
n.cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n.cores, type="FORK")
clusterExport(cl, "myfun")
parSapply(cl, 1:10, myfun)

stopCluster(clust)
```

Error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  8 nodes produced errors; first error: can only subtract from "POSIXt" objects
```

Head of EURUSD:

```
                  Date    Open    High     Low   Close
1  2016-01-03 17:00:00 1.08701 1.08713 1.08701 1.08713
2  2016-01-03 17:01:00 1.08712 1.08712 1.08712 1.08712
3  2016-01-03 17:02:00 1.08708 1.08722 1.08708 1.08722
4  2016-01-03 17:03:00 1.08717 1.08723 1.08717 1.08723
5  2016-01-03 17:04:00 1.08718 1.08718 1.08711 1.08711
6  2016-01-03 17:05:00 1.08703 1.08716 1.08701 1.08712
7  2016-01-03 17:06:00 1.08721 1.08721 1.08710 1.08710
8  2016-01-03 17:07:00 1.08712 1.08715 1.08712 1.08712
9  2016-01-03 17:08:00 1.08711 1.08720 1.08711 1.08713
10 2016-01-03 17:09:00 1.08716 1.08723 1.08708 1.08708
```

Intended outcome:
If (High-Open > limit) then return 1, if (Open - Low > StopLoss) return 0. If neither then compare the same Open price to the High and Low of the next period. When either 1 or 0 is returned then increment Open by + 1 and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what the cause of the problem was, but I fiddled with the code and it now works and thought it may benefit others.

```
library("parallel")
library("doParallel")

n.cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n.cores, type="FORK")
clusterExport(cl, "myfun")
t(parSapply(cl, i:j, function(x) myfun(x, df = EURUSD2, Limit = k, StopLoss = k)))
stopCluster(cl)
```

I added the arguments to the myfun part of parSapply as well as changing the stopCluster argument.